# Converting the Time format in dateTime from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: date, datetime, salesforce, apex, data-conversion

I have converted a Date into DateTime format, and it is returning me the hour format in **00:00:00** but I want it to be in **23:59:59**

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2021,2,1);
```

This returns the output as **2021-02-01 00:00:00**

When I try to convert this to the **23:59:59** hour format by using the below code

```
DateTime startDateConvertTwo = DateTime.newInstance(startDate, Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0));
```

It is pushing the date to next day and returning the value of **2021-02-02 07:59:59**

I  tried to sort this out by changing the values of Time.newInstance by adding it as **Time.newInstance(15, 59, 59, 0)** by doing which I get the expected result. But is it the right way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Please let me know if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned output of `Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2021,2,1);` is not `2021-02-01 00:00:00`. It's just a **date** with no information about time, but `System.debug()` display it as a DateTime, that's why you see `00:00:00`.
Try `System.debug(String.valueOf(startDate));` to see only the Date part.

---

[`DateTime.newInstance(date, time)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

> Constructs a DateTime from the specified date and time in the local time zone.

As documentation states, the DateTime you get is in your own time zone. Anyway  `System.debug()` shows it in UTC time zone (GMT+0), so if your time zone is GMT-8 you'll see `2021-02-02 07:59:59`.
`System.debug(String.valueOf(startDateConvertTwo ));` will shows the DateTime in your own time zone, so you'll see `2021-02-01 23:59:59`.

If you need a DateTime in GMT you could use `DateTime.newInstanceGmt(date, time)`:

```
DateTime startDateGMT = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(startDate, Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0));
```

If you cannot use that method, you could add your offset to a DateTime:

```
public static DateTime toUTC(DateTime value) {
    Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(value);
    return value.addSeconds(offset/1000);
}
```

You could test it in anonymous console:

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2021,2,1);
DateTime startDateConvertTwo = DateTime.newInstance(startDate, Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0));
DateTime startDateGMT = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(startDate, Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0));
DateTime startDateGMT2 = toUTC(startDateConvertTwo);

System.debug('startDateConvertTwo: ' + startDateConvertTwo); // startDateConvertTwo: 2021-02-01 22:59:59 // Because I'm at GMT+1
System.debug('String.valueOf(startDateConvertTwo): ' + String.valueOf(startDateConvertTwo));  // String.valueOf(startDateConvertTwo): 2021-02-01 23:59:59

System.debug('startDateGMT: ' + startDateGMT); // startDateGMT: 2021-02-01 23:59:59 // Now it's in UTC
System.debug('String.valueOf(startDateGMT): ' + String.valueOf(startDateGMT)); // String.valueOf(startDateGMT): 2021-02-02 00:59:59 // So in my locale time it's the day after,

System.debug('startDateGMT2: ' + startDateGMT2); // startDateGMT2: 2021-02-01 23:59:59 // Same as startDateGMT
System.debug('String.valueOf(startDateGMT2): ' + String.valueOf(startDateGMT2)); // String.valueOf(startDateGMT2): 2021-02-02 00:59:59

public static DateTime toUTC(DateTime value) {
    Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(value);
    return value.addSeconds(offset/1000);
}
```

The output of `startDateGMT` and `startDateGMT2` will be the same.

**Noteworthy**: DateTime fields are stored in GMT. When shown in the standard Salesforce UI, they're converted to the user's timezone.